# Default value of members in a struct

Tags: c++

In the struct

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    A(){ }
};

A a;
```

Is it specified which value has `a.a`? Doe we have UB if we try to read `a.a`?

Comment: It's not mandatory for the compiler to initialize the data members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `A a;` has static [storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) (like defining it outside `main()`), or thread storage duration (i.e. defined with `thread_local` in C++11 or later), then `a` is zero-initialized (thanks @Praetorian for the comment)

> **3.6.2/2 [basic.start.init]** Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.

In your case, this means that each member of your object `A a` will be zeroed, hence `a.a` will be zeroed, then the constructor `A()` will run (which won't do anything). At the end of the day, `a.a` will be zero.

If `A a` has non-static/non-thread storage duration (e.g. having `A a;` inside a function), then no zero initialization is performed, and again the constructor doesn't do anything. So you have UB (undefined behaviour) if you try to read `a.a`, since the latter is left un-initialized.

Comment: So for dynamc storage duration we don't have the default too?

Comment: @user3663882 No, you don't have default zero. Not absolutely sure about dynamic objects with static storage duration, like `A* ptr = new A;` outside `main()`, will take a look at the standard.

Comment: BTW, thank you for providing the reference from the Standard. It's really useful for me.

Comment: @user3663882 so no, dynamic objects with static storage duration are not zeroed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have used java you might know that variables are assigned a default value in it but that's not the case in c++. Here you only allocate a chunk of memory for your variable. Whatever garbage it contained before it was allocated to you comes with it. So we call it a garbage value. You have to initialize it to your desired value in the constructor of the class or the structure.